# Adding right swipe gesture recognizer to tab.scrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, gestures

I'm trying to add a swipe right gesture to the showweb view but coming up with errors it's not recognizing it...here is origional code. I want the user to swipe right and be taken to the intput view that they already get with a pan gesture, by swiping down on the show web view.

```
- (void)showWeb
{
    [self.omnibar resignFirstResponder];

    Tab *tab = self.tabs[self.currentTabIndex];
    tab.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


//    tab.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    tab.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^{
//        tab.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -showOffset);
        tab.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(tab.transform.tx, tab.transform.ty-showOffset) ;
    }];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
    self.showingTools = false;


}

- (void)showTools
{
//    [self.omnibar becomeFirstResponder];

    Tab *tab = self.tabs[self.currentTabIndex];
    tab.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
//    tab.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
//        tab.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
        tab.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(tab.transform.tx, tab.transform.ty+showOffset);
    }];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
    self.showingTools = true;

    if (newTabAlpha==1 || tab.request)
    {
        [self updateScreenshotOf:tab];
        [self.omnibar becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code where you added the gesture.. also what do you mean by its not recognizing it?

Comment: I think it'd just me being a noob :/ do you have skype